# How to bind InArgument<Activity> to WorkflowItemPresenter in Custom Activity Designer

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am experiencing wf4, and met some issue. I created an xaml flowchart activity, it helps me control 3 child activites' flow, and I want to have a designer to drag some activities into the 3 child activies, so I created a partial class to the xaml activity and bind the designer with it, the designer has 3 WorkflowItemPresenter.
But I am not able to bind the InArgument to WorkflowItemPresenter, so is there a solution to bind InArgument to WorkflowItemPresenter?

Thanks,
Tong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are trying but an InArgument is normally used for data that changes at runtime and should be serializable. An activity doesn't quite meet that requirement and is normally done using a regular property.